# Reading .kv file in Kivy app

Tags: kivy

I have a file main.py with the following code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse, Line
from kivy.lang import Builder 

from enum import IntEnum
from enum import Enum

from random import random

class Vertice(Widget):
    def __init__(self, pos=None):

        self.pos = pos
        #print self.pos
        print self.size

class Type(IntEnum):
    RIGHT_TOP = 1
    RIGHT_BOTTOM = 2
    LEFT_BOTTOM = 3
    LEFT_TOP = 4
    UNDEFINED = 5

class Direction(Enum):
    CLOCKWISE = 1
    COUNTER_CLOCKWISE = 2
    UNDEFINED = 3

class MindMapWidget(Widget):
    circleShape = [Type.RIGHT_TOP, Type.RIGHT_BOTTOM, Type.LEFT_BOTTOM, Type.LEFT_TOP]
    editing = False
    bounds = []
    vertices = []

    def getType(self, dx, dy, direction):
        result = Type.UNDEFINED

        if direction != Direction.UNDEFINED:
            if dx > 0 and dy > 0:
                if (self.isClockwise(direction)):
                    result = Type.RIGHT_TOP
                else:
                    result = Type.LEFT_BOTTOM
            else:
                if dx < 0 and dy > 0:
                    if (self.isClockwise(direction)):
                        result = Type.RIGHT_BOTTOM
                    else:
                        result = Type.LEFT_TOP
                else:
                    if dx < 0 and dy < 0:
                        if (self.isClockwise(direction)):
                            result = Type.LEFT_BOTTOM
                        else:
                            result = Type.RIGHT_TOP
                    else:
                        if dx > 0 and dy < 0:
                            if (self.isClockwise(direction)):
                                result = Type.LEFT_TOP
                            else:
                                result = Type.RIGHT_BOTTOM

        print result

        return result

    def getPointsXAndY(self, points, index):
        startIndex = index * 2

        return [points[startIndex], points[startIndex + 1]]

    def isClockwise(self, direction):
        return direction == Direction.CLOCKWISE

    def isCircle(self, points, direction): 
        result = False
        shape = self.circleShape
        STEP = 5
        index = 0
        startIndex = 0

        detected = [None] * 4

        currentPoint = self.getPointsXAndY(points, 0)
        currentType = None

        if direction != Direction.UNDEFINED:
            for x in range(STEP, len(points), STEP):
                try:
                    nextPoint = self.getPointsXAndY(points, x)
                except:
                    break

                dx = nextPoint[0] - currentPoint[0]
                dy = -(nextPoint[1] - currentPoint[1])

                if dx == 0 or dy == 0:
                    continue

                newType = self.getType(dx, dy, direction)

                # get the first item, or if the direction has changed
                if currentType is None or currentType != newType:
                    # if we have at least the first direction, check if the next direction is the next step in the circle drawing process
                    if currentType is not None:
                        if newType != shape[index]:
                                break

                    # a circle is a distionct set of drawing directions, so we need to follow them in order, from where the user started drawing
                    else:
                        index = shape.index(newType)
                        startIndex = index

                    self.bounds.insert(index, currentPoint)

                    # don't double up on actions, because we need to compare lists
                    if detected.count(newType) == 0:
                        print index
                        #detected.insert(index, newType)
                        detected[index] = newType

                    # because we may start anywhere in the shape, we may need to do circular traversal of the shape array
                    if direction == Direction.CLOCKWISE:
                        index = (index + 1) % len(shape)
                    else:
                        index = (index - 1) % len(shape)

                currentType = newType
                currentPoint = nextPoint

                if shape == detected:
                    result = True
                    break

        return result


    """def reverseDirection(self, direction):
        result = None

        if direction == Direction.UNDEFINED:
            result = direction
        else:
            if direction == Direction.CLOCKWISE:
                result = Direction.COUNTER_CLOCKWISE
            else:
                result = Direction.CLOCKWISE

        return result"""

    def determineDirection(self, points):
        result = Direction.UNDEFINED
        total = 0
        currentPoint = None
        previousPoint = None

        for i in range(0, len(points)/2, 1):
            currentPoint = self.getPointsXAndY(points, i)

            if previousPoint is not None:
                total += (currentPoint[0] - previousPoint[0]) * (currentPoint[1] + previousPoint[1])

            previousPoint = currentPoint

        if total > 0:
            result = Direction.CLOCKWISE
        else:
            if total < 0:
                result = Direction.COUNTER_CLOCKWISE

        return result

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        editing = True
        color = (random(), 1., 1.)

        with self.canvas:
            Color(*color, mode='hsv')
            touch.ud['line'] = Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y))

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        touch.ud['line'].points += [touch.x, touch.y]

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        editing = False
        direction = None

        if len(touch.ud['line'].points) > 0:
            points = touch.ud['line'].points

            if self.isCircle(points, self.determineDirection(points)):
                print "circle"

                with self.canvas:
                    #Ellipse(pos=(self.bounds[0]), size=(50, 50))
                    Vertice(pos=self.bounds[0])
            else:
                print "unknown"


class MindMapApp(App):

    def build(self):
        parent = Widget()
        painter = MindMapWidget()
        clearbtn = Button(text='Clear')
        parent.add_widget(painter)
        parent.add_widget(clearbtn)

        def clear_canvas(obj):
            painter.canvas.clear()

        clearbtn.bind(on_release=clear_canvas)

        Config.set('input','multitouchscreen1','tuio,192.168.0.4:3333')
        return parent


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MindMapApp().run()
```

I have a mindmap.kv file:

```
#:kivy 1.8

<Vertice>:
    size: 50, 50
    canvas:
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

the output of the statement:

```
 print self.size
```

is:

```
[100,100]
```

which is the default widget size. When the app loads, it throws out this debug:

```
[DEBUG             ] [App         ] Loading kv <./mindmap.kv>
```

This says to me the .kv file is loading and not being interpreted correctly. Am I missing a link? I am unsure how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MindMap.kv should be mindmap.kv i.e. it should be in small letters . please try .

Also in order to run this you need to add below line at the end of your code

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MindMapApp().run()
```

Another way to load .kv file is using builder 
    Builder.load_file('path/to/file.kv')

for more information check http://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html

Change your Vertice Class to following :

```
class Vertice(Widget):
    def __init__(self, pos=None):
        super(Vertice, self).__init__()

        self.pos = pos
        #print self.pos
        print self.size
```

Comment: I already had that in the code, but I excluded it as it was not important to the issue at hand. Changing the name of the file did not fix the issue. Thanks though.

Comment: ok great , then try renaming your .kv file to lowercase letters .

Comment: Yes, both in the same directory.

Comment: have you tried Builder.load_file('path/to/file.kv') also ?

Comment: No, where would I put that statement? And can the path be relative? I.e. as they're in the same directory, simply put Builder.load('mindmap.kv') ?

Comment: you need to import Builder i.e.
from kivy.lang import Builder

and then you can add Builder.load('mindmap.kv')  in build method of your App class

Comment: Add your complete code , may be then i can help you more :)

Comment: Add this line in your Vertice Class 

super(Vertice, self).__init__()